# How to build .vdproj msi using TeamCity?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, continuous-integration, teamcity, teamcity-7.1

I am trying to get continuous integration setup using TeamCity to automatically build and release our application and Windows services.  The solution currently consists of a web application and 2 services (amongst a host of other projects, but all that gets deployed is the app and services) - the services are packaged into .msi installers using Visual Studio 2010 setup projects (`.vdproj`).

The web application isn't an issue because I can just use `MsBuild.exe` to publish.  However, `MsBuild.exe` doesn't build `.vdproj` projects.  One solution I've come across is to use `devenv.com`, e.g. `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" SolutionFile.sln /Build "Release" /Project SetupProjectFile.vdproj`.

I'm new to TeamCity so I don't know how to approach this.  I've tried adding a build step using the `Command Line` runner, but that just fails with the error `(Command Line) failed`.  How do you achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using msbuild scripts. Msbuild scripts can be specified in Teamcity and you can pass in parameters to customise it as well.

Another good read is [Implementing TeamCity for .NET Projects, Part 4: Using Build Scripts](http://elegantcode.com/2009/05/24/implementing-teamcity-for-net-projects-part-4-using-build-scripts/) by [Elegant Code](http://elegantcode.com/about/) Blogging Community.

Answer (score 3):

You could install Visual studio on build server, and run devenv.exe from a commandline build runner in TeamCity. It doesn't feel right, but I think it will work. See [this link](http://www.tandisoft.com/2011/08/building-visual-studio-setup-projects.html).

Comment: This is the way to go if you stillwant to use `.vdproj`'s. A better solution is to migrate to Wix, which is completely MsBuild compatible.

Comment: Worked fine for me. Thanks!