# TeamCity can't build vdproj - HRESULT = '8000000A'

Tags: teamcity, build-server, devenv, vdproj

I'm using TeamCity to build nightly a .vdproj installer.

I'm using this configuration in TeamCity v10:

[image]

but I got this error message

```
ERROR: An error occurred while validating.  HRESULT = '8000000A'
```

I already put into regedit the DWORD `EnableOutOfProcBuild` with `value=0` but seems that it works only if I run the command through the CMD and not via TeamCity.

I've also tried to put a delay between build steps, using the config below, but it doesn't work:

[image]

I use VS2015 and I've installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects extension

Any solution?

Thanks

Comment: You can find due command to work from the command line and only then configure that in TeamCity, ensuring the same environment (user, env variables,  starting TeamCity agent from the same command prompt window, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24315937/355465). It involves calling devenv.exe from a commandline build runner. Not the cleanest solution but worked fine for me.